# Create an iframe widget loaded using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed

I want to create an iframe widget loaded using javascript like drift.com
I Want to include a code like the one bellow: 
This one loads an iframe and places it on the bottom of the page. How Can I do something similar? I want to add an Iframe but I want to give a javascript snippet.

```
  ! function() {
    var t;
    if (t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [], !t.init) return t.invoked ? void(window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice.")) : (t.invoked = !0,
        t.methods = ["identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on"],
        t.factory = function(e) {
            return function() {
                var n;
                return n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
            };
        }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
            t[e] = t.factory(e);
        }), t.load = function(t) {
            var e, n, o, i;
            e = 3e5, i = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script"),
                o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + i + "/" + t + ".js",
                n = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], n.parentNode.insertBefore(o, n);
        });
}();
drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
drift.load('aczfy2anahyv');
```